# MySQL UPDATE trigger: INSERTing the values of the columns that actually changed

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm working on a fairly simple ticket managment system. I want to keep a log for stuff that gets added, deleted, and changed.

I created three triggers, `AFTER INSERT`, `AFTER DELETE`, and `AFTER UPDATE`. The `INSERT`/`DELETE` triggers are straightforward, it's the`UPDATE` trigger I'm having problems with.

I would like to add which columns has changed in the table with their old & new values, i.e. `colname changed from X to Y`

The trigger I have now "works", except of course that it doesn't insert the actual values I'd like.

**How do I get the value from `OLD` and `NEW` using the `col_name` variable?**

I'm also not sure if this is the *best* possible way of doing this ... So if anyone has ideas on that, they're welcome too ... This trigger started out a lot simpler ...

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE num_rows, i int default 1;
    DECLARE col_name CHAR(255);
    DECLARE updated TEXT;

    DECLARE col_names CURSOR FOR
        SELECT column_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE table_name = 'storing'
        ORDER BY ordinal_position;

    OPEN col_names;
    SELECT FOUND_ROWS() INTO num_rows;
    SET i = 1;
    SET @updated = 'Updated columns: ';

    the_loop: LOOP
        IF i > num_rows THEN
            LEAVE the_loop;
        END IF;

        FETCH col_names INTO col_name;

        /* So, how do I get the proper values? */
        /* IF NEW.@col_name != OLD.@col_name THEN */
        /*SET @updated = CONCAT(@updated, OLD.@col_name, ' changed into ', NEW.@col_name, ' ');*/
        SET @updated = CONCAT(@updated, 'OLD', ' changed into ', 'NEW', ' ');
        /* END IF;*/

        SET i = i + 1;
    END LOOP the_loop;

    CLOSE col_names;

    INSERT INTO `log` (`storing`, `medewerker`, `actie`, `data`)
    VALUES (NEW.`id`, NEW.`medewerker`, "Storing aangepast", @updated);
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Since usage of prepared statements here is impossible, I would suggest you to call some INSERT statements, e.g. -

   IF NEW.column1 <> OLD.column1 THEN
     INSERT INTO...
   END IF;
   IF NEW.column2 <> OLD.column2 THEN
     INSERT INTO...
   END IF;
   ...
2. Or try to copy all fields you need into another table.

In these cases you will avoid using cursor.

Comment: Thanks, this works and I implemented it (The first) as a temporary solution, but to be honest it's not really very pretty ... I'd much rather loop over the column names...

Comment: So I went with this in the end. It might not look particularly pretty, but I guess columns won't change that much and it's a hell of a lot simpler (== less to go wrong, less to understand for future maintainers, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html)
Something like this:

```
SET @s = CONCAT('SELECT new.', @col_name, ', old.', @col_name, ' FROM ', /*here is the query details like inner joins etc.*/, ' where ', 'NEW.', @col_name, '!= OLD.', @col_name )
    PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
    EXECUTE stmt;
```

Comment: From the reference - SQL syntax for prepared statements can be used within stored procedures, but not in stored functions or triggers. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html

Comment: Yes, you're right... Idea: we can copy OLD and NEW contents to some temporary table(s) and call a stored procedure that will create and execute prepared statement. But it would be very expensive.